# Finding Active Language in org with Translation Workbench enabled

Tags: apex, visualforce, translation

I'd like to add onto a VF page a dropdown with the active languages set in the translation workbench. The idea is to load another VF page setting the language to the chosen value from the dropdown list.

I can do everything I need except build the list of languages the user can choose from. Is it possible to 'query the translation workbench' and find these active languages?

From this example I need to find English, German, Japanese and Korean.

[image: Screen showing translation WB langauges screen for ref.]

Answer (score 3):

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqyLAAS

Looks like its an idea and currently the translation workbench is not exposed as an API

Since a metadata is exposed for this its doable only through apex metadata wrapper developed by MVP andrew .Have a look at below to explore more

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

May be you will have to look at retrive call of metadata
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieve.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mohith. Not sure I need to go to the trouble of accessing through a metadata wrapper - too much like hard work! I'm going to add a custom setting and the users will have to keep everything in sync. Not an elegant solution but will do for the time I have available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can now be done via a simple SOQL query:

```
Select Id, Language, IsActive from Translation
```

The full documentation is here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_translation.htm